# Handling data skewness and kurtosis

Tags: transformation

I have a dataset where the variables have high skewness (> ±1) and kurtosis (> ±5). I tried to remove outliers and log10 transformation the skewness and kurtosis are still high. Are there any aspects that I should take note of as well?

Comment: Can you show a histogram / density plot of your data?

Answer (score 0):

A few questions in regards to your dataset.

1. What's the size of the dataset?
2. What ML technique/modeling technique do you want to deploy with the dataset? ex. Linear regression, Clustering, etc

In general, your approach to using **log transformation** is the right way to go, as in most cases that does the trick. But in other cases (depending on how high the skewness is, plotting the variables here helps to gauge the skewness better), you should explore techniques such as (but not limited to) **Square Root transform** and **Box Cox Transform**.

Here is a reference https://towardsdatascience.com/top-3-methods-for-handling-skewed-data-1334e0debf45

Comment: My dataset size is around 1,000 and I plan to apply linear regression. Hence, that is why I am trying to normalize it.

Comment: perfect, then the techniques mentioned above should help you in reducing the skewness. Please let me know, in case neither of the above techniques helps in reducing the skewness,